# Интересный тест с сайта quizful

Tags: java

Наткнулся на странный вопрос из теста. Что выведется при сравнении **i1,i3** .Ответ: тру.
Меня одного это смущает?

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
class ArraysComparing { 
public static void main(String...args) { 
    int[] i1[] = {{1,2,3}, {0,0,0}}; 
    int[][] i2 = {{1,2,3}, {0,0,0,}}; 
    int[][] i3 = new int[2][3]; 
    System.arraycopy(i1, 0, i3, 0, i3.length); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(i1, i2)); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(i1, i3)); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(i1, i2)); 
} 
}
```

И еще вопрос :

```
package question;

 import java.io.BufferedOutputStream; 
 import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
 import java.io.IOException; 
 import java.io.PrintStream;

  public class TestOutput { 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream( 
               new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.out"))); 
    PrintStream console = System.out; 
    System.setOut(console);

    System.out.println("FIRST OUTPUT");

    System.setOut(out);

    System.out.println("SECOND OUTPUT");

    out.close();

    System.out.println("THIRD OUTPUT"); 
} 
}
```

Почему в этом коде после закрытия потока вывод не произойдет в стандартный поток в консоль? Ведь после закрытия мы должны получить замещение имени **out** на стандартный поток вывода.

Comment: Там коипурется один массив в другой

    System.arraycopy(i1, 0, i3, 0, i3.length);

По этому  

    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(i1, i3));    

Вернёт true

Comment: так копируются значения массива?!

Comment: @voipp, полагаю, вам стоит заглянуть в сорцы `java.util.Arrays`.

Comment: я выяснил, что arraycopy - native метод, более того, он написан да C.

Comment: С чем вас и поздравляю. Но какое это имеет отношение к рекомендации посмотреть, как устроен `Arrays.equals()` и `Arrays.deepEquals()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> но копируются значения, а сами ссылки
> все равно отличаются.

Что? Вы копируете массив ссылок.
Ссылки на массивы первого уровня i1 и i3 разные.
Но они содержат одно и тоже, т.е. ссылки на вложенные массивы.
Не верите мне, проверьте в отладчике.

По второй части. Компы вообще тупые(пока) и делают то, что им скажут.
Вот он и закрыл поток вывода, а не переключился на SDTOUT.
Думаю это особенность java-машины.